# Switching from UIWebView to WKWebView Delegates

Tags: swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

What would the equivalent of

```
webView.delegate = self
```

Be in a WKWebView? I have

```
webView2.UIDelegate = self
```

But it does not work as intended.

Comment: There is the `navigationDelegate` which allows you to handle page load events.

Comment: Doesn't let me use tap gestures

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Add a tap gesture recognizer to interact with the web view HTML content?

Comment: Add a tap gesture to add a border around the view

Comment: When the view is tapped

Comment: Do you want to add a tap gesture to one part of the web view? Or to the whole web view?

Comment: The whole web view. Trying to convert [this project](https://github.com/twostraws/HackingWithSwift/tree/master/project31) to WKWebViews

Comment: The tap gesture recognizer has nothing to do with the web view delegate. What exact problem are you having?

Comment: Tapping the view and the border appearing doesn't work since changing over to WKWebView and the only difference is the delegate line.

Answer (score 7):

You can monitor WKWebView's canGoBack and canGoForward, using key-value observing.

SWIFT 3

Add two key-value observers to WKWebView.

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame)
view.addSubview(webView)

webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.canGoBack), options: .new, context: nil)
webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.canGoForward), options: .new, context: nil)
```

Now, implement observeValue(forKeyPath:) method in your view controller.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if keyPath == #keyPath(WKWebView.canGoBack) || keyPath == #keyPath(WKWebView.canGoForward) {
        // Do Something...
    }
}
```

For example, you can add something like this to the change tint color of the buttons.

```
backButton.imageView?.tintColor = webView.canGoBack ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.gray
forwardButton.imageView?.tintColor = webView.canGoBack ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.gray
```

I found this method by reading an article from here.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/wkwebview/how-to-monitor-wkwebview-page-load-progress-using-key-value-observing

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `only` change to the code is changing `UIWebView` to `WKWebView`? I have made a sample project and the tap gesture recognizer worked for both `UIWebView` and `WKWebView`. Here is the relevant code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame)
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let urlString = "https://www.google.com"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)

        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(webViewTapped))
        recognizer.delegate = self
        webView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func webViewTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Tapped")
    }
}
```

Comment: It must be in my functions following the view being tapped.